# Columns by Hour of the day

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, time

I have a data table with 2 relevant columns in a database

router_destination_code

app_last_updated_date_utc   <- This is a timestamp

I'm trying to generate a report that will show individual destination codes as rows and each hour of the day as columns (24 Columns, 00:00-01:00 as hour 1, 0100 - 0200 as hour 2, exc).

I have it by the whole day, but am at a loss to get columns to represent each hour aside from making 23 unions.

This is my code for a 24 hour period:

```
Select router_destination_code as Destination, count(Router_Destination_code) as Shipments
from booker.routing_container_history
where app_last_updated_by_module in ('ManualSlam', 'slam')
and app_last_updated_date_utc between 'dec/07/2013 16:00:00' and 'dec/08/2013 16:00:00'
Group by router_destination_code
order by count(Router_Destination_code) desc
```

I'm Running:

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer v3.2.20.09

Comment: what version of oracle? 10g? 11g? other? pivot command of SQL will take the hours to columns.  to get hours you have a couple of choices.  `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)` will give you hour of day.  or you can use to_Char(timestamp, 'HH24') to get a string value.

Comment: What does "in date time format" mean?  Is the column a `date`?  A `timestamp`?  A `varchar2` that represents a date or a timestamp in some format?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production   is what version it's running. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer v3.2.20.09

Comment: Sorry for the spam:

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production. 

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer v3.2.20.09

It's a timestamp

Comment: add `extract(hour from app_last_Updated_Date_Utc)` to select and group by to get your hour.  Then look up how to use `PIVOT` in oracle to pivot on the extracted hour to get your desired results. such as: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506